# Custom password hashing function for Cerberus SFTP server

Tags: encryption, cryptography, sftp, pbkdf2

I'm trying to migrate users from our legacy Cerberus SFTP server to a new AWS Transfer Family SFTP server. The problem is most of our Cerberus users have password based authentication and all I have access to is their one-way hashed password. Thus I'm trying to reverse engineer how Cerberus hashes it's password so I don't have to ask our 100+ customers to submit a new password to use or switch to a public key based authentication.

I came across this blog post that I think details how to do it but I can't seem to get it to work for some reason - https://support.cerberusftp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000040039-Securely-Storing-User-Passwords.

Here are the steps I've taken so far -

1. created a user in Cerberus with a password of "asdf"
2. exported my collection of users to a CSV file
3. identified the hashed password from the export as follows -
   {{PBKDF2 HMAC SHA256}}:5000:42ED67592D7D80F03BF3E2413EB80718C5DAFEB5237FC4E5E309C2940DF1DBB2A4ABD9BB63B8AD285858B532A573D9DE
4. attempted to write a Python script that could hash "asdf" to the same hash as shown above

Here is what my script looks like so far - https://replit.com/@ryangrush/sample.

```
import hashlib
import base64

password = b'asdf'
salt = b'sample_salt'

combined = salt + password
first = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', combined, b'', 5000)
combined = salt + first
second = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', combined, b'', 5000)
base_16 = base64.b16encode(second)

print(second.hex())
print(base_16)
```

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk sorry I should've been more clear. I'm not trying to recover the original password, I know that's not easily possible with one-way hashing. I'm trying to recreate Cerberus's hashing method outside of Cerberus so I verify "yes this is the same password they used originally" or "no this password does not match".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://support.cerberusftp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000040039-Securely-Storing-User-Passwords) must've been written before the v7.0 PBKDF2 HMAC functions were adopted. The salt and the password are now used just as described in the documentation for [PBKDF2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac).

```py
import hashlib
import base64

hashed_password_entry = '{{PBKDF2 HMAC SHA256}}:5000:42ED67592D7D80F03BF3E2413EB80718C5DAFEB5237FC4E5E309C2940DF1DBB2A4ABD9BB63B8AD285858B532A573D9DE'
entry_components_strings = hashed_password_entry.split(':')
password = b'asdf'

iterations = int(entry_components_strings[1])
salt_plus_hashvalue = base64.b16decode(entry_components_strings[2])
hash_len = 256 // 8
salt, hashvalue = salt_plus_hashvalue[:-hash_len], salt_plus_hashvalue[-hash_len:]

hashvalue_test = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('SHA256', password, salt, iterations)
print(hashvalue_test.hex())
```

the output is `c5dafeb5237fc4e5e309c2940df1dbb2a4abd9bb63b8ad285858b532a573d9de` which you can see matches the hashed value that is at the end of entry.

Comment:  thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed! Thanks for breaking it down like you did too, I finally understand how you separate the salt from the hash!